# Five sets of related questions will reveal the answer

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge

Hopefully you are able to solve the questions and reveal the answer. Any constructive comments on this question would be appreciated. Hope you have fun:

---

1a. 0x53 0x4A Dr from Baker Street

1b. Previously myself, move towards drop off

---

2a. Also .-. . .-- Operator of a quern-stone

2b. Third most abundant element in the universe

---

3a. An unknown Doe with a large German glass drinks a Northern English stream.

3b. Belong to pests as well as fellas

---

4a. Motivation I think therefore quiver with what sounds like fear

4b. His majesty and left initial aside a wax-producing organ

---

5a. A single beam of light joined the first half of a Pit that was filled in.

5b. An object mischievously approaches

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, great first question and thank you for contributing!

Comment: I added the [tag:word] tag, indicating that the answer will be 1 or more  words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A literal approach gives these as clues to

> a) authors and b) one of their works

1a. 0x53 0x4A Dr from Baker Street

> SJ Watson  [Ascii 0x53 0x4A gives *SJ*]

1b. Previously myself, move towards drop off

> Before I Go To Sleep

2a. Also .-. . .-- .-.-.. .-.-.. Operator of a quern-stone

> Andrew Miller  [*And* (also) + Morse code (*rew*)] + *Miller* (grinds quern-stone)

2b. Third most abundant element in the universe

> Oxygen

3a. An unknown Doe with a large German glass drinks a Northern English stream.

> John Steinbeck [*John* (Doe) + *Stein* + *beck* (stream)]

3b. Belong to pests as well as fellas

> Of mice and men

4a. Motivation I think therefore quiver with what sounds like fear

> William Shakespeare [*Will* + I think therefore *I am* + *Shake* + *spear* sound

4b. His majesty and left initial aside a wax-producing organ

> King Lear

5a. A single beam of light joined the first half of a Pit that was filled in.

> Ray Bradbury  [*Ray* + *Brad*(Pitt) + *bury*]

5b. An object mischievously approaches

> Something Wicked This Way Comes

The final answer was found by, and see [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66882/19547), for the wrap-up which is:

> When you take the first letters of the works, the word BOOKS appears.

Comment: Dern it all, was *this* close when I saw the dreaded "There is 1 new answer to this post" message

Comment: All correct, did you also find a hidden answer?

Comment: I missed the final connection! (I had at first thought there would be - nice one - but didn't see a relation between the authors as they progressed, from different ages, so then thought maybe just some of your favourites.) It was fun answering and neat clues.

Comment: @tom They were based on books that I enjoyed reading apart from King Lear which I had to read at school. Something Wicked This Way Comes i have read three times as well as most of his other stories. Thanks for giving this a go and your comments.

Answer (score 8):

@Tom answered all the questions (+1, well done!), but there's perhaps a final hidden answer.

> When you take the first letters of the works:
>  1. Before I Go To Sleep
>  2. Oxygen
>  3. Of mice and men
>  4. King Lear
>  5. Something Wicked This Way Comes
>  the word **BOOKS** appears.

Comment: It was intentional, but perhaps I should have phrased the question better with 'hidden answer'. Now a quandary, who do I mark as the correct answer!

Comment: I'm OK with @Tom adding this (with attribution) to his answer, so you can accept it; he did the lion's share of the work.

Comment: Great spot (I missed that)!  Thanks also for suggesting to add to the separate clues.